# Error Uploading the apk on Amazon App Store

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

I'm trying to upload a newer version of my Android app on Amazon App Store, but encountered the following error,,

```
Failed to upload binary. The package name of the uploaded binary does not match the one in the previous version.
```

I'm sure the package name has not been changed from the previous version. Suggest me how to overcome this error.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Amazon forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=551):-

> You get this message whenever the package name of the new binary to be
>   uploaded is different than that of the previous version. Please ensure
>   that the package name of the new binary is same as that of the
>   previous version.
>
> The existing package name can be found under the previous version's
>   Binary File(s) tab, Binary file section.